# how to grep a hex data area

Tags: bash, grep, range, hex

I have a hex file, I need to extract a range of it to a text file

**From range:**

[image]

**To Range:**

[image]

**I need Output:** *AC:E4:B5:9A:53:1C*

i tried many but it not really correct requirements, Output: `Binary file filehex matches`

```
grep "["'\x9f\x87\x6f\x11'"-"'\x9f\x87\x70\x11'"]" filehex > test.txt
```

hope someone can help me

Comment: Use `-a` to force the ASCII (i.e. not binary) interpretation.

Comment: You have to use a tool able to merge two lines. [tag:sed] is the lighter one! see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68482514/1765658).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-a` to force the text interpretation of the input.

Use `-o` to only output the matching part.

The expression you used doesn't make much sense. It matches any characters in the set \x9, \x87, \x6f, and then the range \x11-\x9f, etc.

You are rather interested in something that starts with \x9\x87\x6f\x11 and ends in \x9f\x87\x70\x11, and there can be anything in between.

You can use `cut` to remove the leading and trailing 4 bytes.

```
grep -oa $'\x9f\x87\x6f\x11.*\x9f\x87\x70\x11' hexfile | cut -b5-21
```

If you know the length of the string will always be 17 bytes, you can use `.\{17\}` instead of `.*`.

Comment: i tried it, it runs smoothly and nothing seems to happen. output is empty

Comment: I generated the input with `echo $'BEFORE\x9f\x87\x6f\x11AC:E4:B5:9A:53:1C\x9f\x87\x70\x11AFTER'` and it worked.

Comment: Sucess!! Thank You! LC_ALL=C grep -oa $'\x9f\x87\x6f\x11.*\x9f\x87\x70\x11' hexfile | cut -b5-21

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've build randomly one binary *`$file`*
with your *string* at a location making `hd` command to split them.

**Note:** regarding [k314159' comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121029506?noredirect=1) I use `hd` to produce *hexdump* output similarto CentOS's `hexdump` tool.

### One shoot using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
hd $file |sed -e 'N;/ 9f \+\(|.*\n[0-9a-f]\+ \+\|\)87 \+\(|.*\n[0-9a-f]\+ \+\|\)6f \+\(|.*\n[0-9a-f]\+ \+\|\)11 /p;D;'
000161c0  96 7a b2 21 28 f1 b3 32  63 43 93 ff 50 a6 9f 87  |.z.!(..2cC..P...|
000161d0  6f 11 0d 7a a5 a9 81 9e  32 9d fb 71 27 6d 60 f2  |o..z....2..q'm`.|
0002c3a0
```

Explanation:

- `N` merge next line in *current buffer*
- `\(|.*\n[0-9a-f]\+ \+\|\)` match a `|` followed by anything and a *newline* (`\n`), then immediately an hexadecimal number and a space OR nothing.
- `p` print *current buffer* (two lines)
- `D` Delete upto *newline* in *current buffer*, keep last line for next sed loop.
  The last hexadecimal  `00028d2a` correspond to the size of my binary `$file`:

  ```
  printf "%x\n" $(stat -c %s $file)
  ```

### Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) + [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
printf -v var "\x9f\x87\x6f\x11" 
IFS=: read -r offset _ < <(grep -abo "$var" $file)
hd $file | sed -ne "$((offset/16-1)),+4p"
000161a0  b7 8f 4a 4d ed 89 6c 0b  25 f9 e7 c9 8c 99 6e 23  |..JM..l.%.....n#|
000161b0  3c ba 80 ec 2e 32 dd f3  a4 a2 09 bd 74 bf 66 11  |<....2......t.f.|
000161c0  96 7a b2 21 28 f1 b3 32  63 43 93 ff 50 a6 9f 87  |.z.!(..2cC..P...|
000161d0  6f 11 0d 7a a5 a9 81 9e  32 9d fb 71 27 6d 60 f2  |o..z....2..q'm`.|
000161e0  15 86 c2 bd 11 d0 08 90  c4 84 b9 80 04 4e 17 f1  |.............N..|
```

Where you could read your string:

```
000161c0                                             9f 87  |              ..|
000161d0  6f 11                                             |o.              |
```

#### For testing, I've built my test file by:

```
dd if=/vmlinuz bs=90574 count=1 of=/tmp/testfile
printf '\x9f\x87\x6f\x11' >>/tmp/testfile 
dd if=/vmlinuz bs=90574 count=1 >>/tmp/testfile
file=/tmp/testfile
```

Comment: You should clarify that `hd` is equivalent to `hexdump`. On some systems, such as CentOS, it is [something completely different](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?manpath=CentOS+7.1&query=hd).

Answer (score 1):

Use grep to search for the original binary file, not the hex dump. Extending [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481048/13963086), I think you may have problems with `grep` trying to interpret your search pattern as UTF-8 or some other encoding. You should temporarily set the environment variable `LC_ALL=C` for grep to treat each byte individually. Also, you can use the `-P` option to enable use of [lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) in your pattern. So your command becomes:

```
LANG=C grep -oaP $'(?<=\x9f\x87\x6f\x11).*(?=\x9f\x87\x70\x11)' binary-file > test.txt
```

Proof that it works:

```
$ echo $'BEFORE\x9f\x87\x6f\x11AC:E4:B5:9A:53:1C\x9f\x87\x70\x11AFTER' | LANG=C grep -oaP $'(?<=\x9f\x87\x6f\x11).*(?=\x9f\x87\x70\x11)'
AC:E4:B5:9A:53:1C
$
```